# Why I am getting 'valueForUndefinedKey' error when using AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, anyobject

Im have a question. Why the following crash reason? since "name" exists?

viewcontroller1:

```
struct pointDict {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
var pointsPlane: [pointDict] = []

let wp = pointDict(id: 123, name: "test")
pointsPlane.append(wp)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


if let destVC = segue.destination as? viewcontroller2 {
destVC.dt = pointsPlane[0] as AnyObject

}
}
```

viewcontroller2:

```
var dt: AnyObject?
let detail = self.dt
name.text = detail?.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
```

Crash Report:

> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
> for the key name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnyObject` is reference type but a struct is value type and therefore is not ObjC key-value coding compliant.

Your approach is bad practice anyway. A *swiftier* way is to declare the properties with the real type. The default declaration of `detail` in the template is not needed.

viewcontroller1:

```
struct PointDict {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
var pointsPlane: [PointDict] = []

let wp = PointDict(id: 123, name: "test")
pointsPlane.append(wp)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
    if let destVC = segue.destination as? viewcontroller2 {
        destVC.dt = pointsPlane.first
    }
}
```

viewcontroller2:

```
var dt : PointDict? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    name.text = dt?.name ?? ""
}
```

Comment: destVC.dt = pointsPlane.first 
>> 
Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController1.pointDict?' to type 'ViewController2.pointDict?'

Comment: Declare the struct outside of `viewcontroller1`(preferred)  or declare dt `var dt : ViewController1.PointDict? `